# Tile rows of a 2D numpy array based on values in separate numpy vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a source array:

```
a = array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
           [3, 4, 5, 6],
           [7, 7, 7, 8]])
```

And a vector that indicates how many times I want to tile each row of the array:

```
count = array([3, 1, 2])
```

I want to get:

```
results =array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
                [1, 1, 2, 2],
                [1, 1, 2, 2],
                [3, 4, 5, 6],
                [7, 7, 7, 8],
                [7, 7, 7, 8]]
```

Is there a vectorized/numpy way to achieve this?

Currently I'm using an iterative loop approach and it's horribly slow when len(a) and/or count contains high values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.repeat()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is what you are after:

**Code:**

```
np.repeat(a, count, axis=0)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
              [3, 4, 5, 6],
              [7, 7, 7, 8]])

count = np.array([3, 1, 2])

print(np.repeat(a, count, axis=0))
```

**Results:**

```
[[1 1 2 2]
 [1 1 2 2]
 [1 1 2 2]
 [3 4 5 6]
 [7 7 7 8]
 [7 7 7 8]]
```